# How do i add a attribute group to a specific product after the creation of the product?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to add an attribute group for some specific group of products and I want the attribute group will be added to the product after it's creation.

Any help would be appreciable...

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

First You have to create the attribute..

```
Admin->Catalog->Manage Attributes->Add new Attribute
```

Then

```
Admin->catalog->Manage Attribute Sets->Add New Set..
```

Drag the newly created Attributes to the New Attribute set and save the set..

Then when create the product choose the newly created attribute set..

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply..But I want to do it programmatically. I want to add attribute group not attribute set and the attribute group should be added to the product after the product creation...